# How can I detect if the browser is capable of running an Angular 16 application

Tags: angular, cross-browser

I want to update a mature Angular application (in production 10+ years; currently at Angular 10) to Angular 16. We have a global user base that includes a wide range of browsers/devices. We know many of our users are on old browsers that are incompatible with Angular 16. We also know from experience that those very users simply will not heed our "please upgrade your browser" warnings until they are forced to do so.

I'm working on a way to force that cohort of legacy browser users to upgrade while minimizing the interruptions for users who are already in compliance.

Here's what I know:

When an incompatible browser attempts to load and execute the script tags that are injected into the page by the Angular 16 build process, JavaScript errors occur and the JS engine crashes. This prevents any other JavaScript code from running so JavaScript browser version testing is also prevented. Preliminary tests in the latest Chrome show that these errors can be avoid by removing the static  tags from the index page. For the happy path, these tags can be programmatically injected into the DOM and modern browsers are still able to run the app. The sad path is handled with a JavaScript redirect to a static page with a final "refusing to upgrade is no longer an option" message. The errors are prevented and the user knows what they need to do.

My challenge is coming up with a reliable way to determine if the browser is Angular 16 incompatible before doing the redirect.

I considered querying the `userAgent` string to check for Edge 85, Safari 14, Chrome 85, Firefox 90 or higher (determined with manual tests on SauceLabs) but [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) recommend against it:

> Using the user agent to detect the browser looks simple, but doing it well is, in fact, a very hard problem.

The official Angular documentation on [browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) states that they test every pull request on the two most recent versions of the major browsers but we know apps will work on more than just that small subset of browsers so the "most recent two versions" is a little too restrictive for my liking.

That MDN page recommends the "browser feature detection" approach as an alternative to user agent detection. The problem is that I don't know what combination of features the browser requires to fully support an Angular 16 application. Is there a list of features that we can check for to be reasonably confident that a browser is compatible with Angular 16?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

EDIT: In case someone else faces the same problem, this is what I've settled on for now:

```js
/**
 * determines if an Angular app should work in this browser
 * @returns boolean
 */
function angularIsNotSupportedInThisBrowser() {
  return (
    typeof Promise === "undefined" ||
    typeof Map === "undefined" ||
    typeof Set === "undefined" ||
    typeof Object.assign === "undefined" ||
    typeof Symbol === "undefined" ||
    typeof JSON === "undefined"
  );
}
```

My experiments are still a moving target but you can check them out [here](https://github.com/rodnolan/rodnolan.github.io) and [here](https://rodnolan.github.io)

EDIT 2: I ended up adding @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser to the mix for this task. I used it to do a transform on the source code for the generated index.html file. The transformer script just replaced the static script tags with an old-browser friendly  javascript function that generated them on the fly. This was combined with the detection script mentioned above to only serve the angular app to browsers that won't crash on load.

Comment: User Agent detection isn't the best idea if you're looking for compatibility with a single feature (there are more elegant ways) and I suspect that's a major reason for recommending against it. There's no need to maintain a list of "go"/"no go" browsers for a single feature. But... If you're checking for compatibility with Angular, it might be simpler to check against the User Agent than to individually check all the possible features a browser might be missing to run the Angular features you're shipping.

Comment: That's a pretty opinionated answer, though. +1 and hopefully someone has something more concrete for you.